Make tooltip follow the cursor on a pie chart with amCharts 5
I'm trying to find a way for the tooltip to follow the cursor when I hover on a slice. The default behavior makes the tooltip stays in a fixed position inside the slice.
Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to get the mouse position and change the position of the tooltip manually?


var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));

var tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
  labelText: "I want to follow the cursor",
})

var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "category",
  tooltip
}));

series.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);
series.ticks.template.set("forceHidden", true);

series.data.setAll([
  { value: 10, category: "One" },
  { value: 9, category: "Two" },
  { value: 6, category: "Three" },
  { value: 5, category: "Four" },
  { value: 4, category: "Five" },
  { value: 3, category: "Six" },
  { value: 1, category: "Seven" },
]);

series.appear(1000, 100);
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>




Please setup a working example so that you and others can experiment
